# Problems with downloading Python module (keyboard)

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am trying to download a module for python version 3.6:
'keyboard'

I go onto Powershell, running in administrator and type:

`py -m pip install keyboard`

It writes back:

> "Requirement already satisfied: keyboard in c:\program files
>   (x86)\microsoft visual studio\shared\python36_64\l" ib\site-packages",

as I have already done this, also when I type:

```
py -m pip list
```

The '`keyboard`' module is there.
However, when I try to import the 'keyboard' module from inside my python script, I get an error of `'ModuleNotFoundError'`

How do I get my keyboard module working?

Comment: What if you use `py -m pip list`?

Comment: Looks like they're calling different pips

Comment: When I type py -m pip list, i get 'keyboard' module there, but it still says ModuleNotFoundError in my code.

Comment: How do you call your script?

Comment: This is common when multiple Python versions are installed side by side. You must identify the version where you need and pass it to `py`. For example for a 3.5 version 32 bits you would use `py -3.5-32 -m pip ...`

Comment: @Serge Ballesta     How would i find the current version of python?

Answer (score 0):

use this line

```
py -m pip3 install keyboard
```

Answer (score 0):

For some odd reason,

I found the answer by instead of typing:

```
py -m pip install keyboard
```

I typed:

```
python -m pip install keyboard
```

And it worked.

Comment: py is calling a different `.exe` than python. Something to do with your environment variables.